# Is it possible to change the color of the pages links to red in MediaWiki?

Tags: colors, hyperlink, mediawiki

I've created a structure with all the pages I'm going to fill in later.
Is it possible to change the color of the links to those pages to red so I could differentiate those pages from the ones that I've already modified?
For the structure I use CategoryTree extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably use the [HtmlPageLinkRendererEnd](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/HtmlPageLinkRendererEnd) hook.